# O is the point of intersection of the diagonals of square ABCD. K is a point on AB such that AK=AO. Find the size of angle KOB

Tags: geometry

i am thinking that the drawing of this would be a square labeled ABCD with the diagonals coming out to create intersection O. Line AB and AO I've marked as equal, but i do not know what to do from here

Answer (score 0):

Triangle $AKO$ is an isosceles triangle, with $\angle OAK = 45°$ (why?). Thus, $\angle AOK$ must be $$\frac12 \left( 180°-45° \right) = 67.5°$$

Now notice that because the diagonals are orthogonal, $\angle AOB = 90°$ and from here we get that $$\angle KOB = \angle AOB - \angle AOK =  90°-67.5° = 22.5°$$

[image]